# In it basic, how do I add one to a variable?

Tags: ti-basic

I am creating a Pac-Man game on a ti-83, and need to add one to a output variable to move a character. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the STO button, above the on button. Write the variable plus one, STO, and then the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the store arrow for this.

Located above the `[on]` key is the `sto`

If your variable is `A`, your code would be `A+1→A`, where `→` represents the symbol typed by that key.

You can read more about it on this page: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/sk:variables